# How to vectorize the evaluation of a quadratic form (x' * A * x)?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

If I have a matrix `A` and I want to evaluate `x' * A * x` for multiple values of `x`, how can I vectorize this?

(I could do `X' * A * X` and take the diagonal, but this is clearly inefficient.)

Comment: Each `x` is a column vector, right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way to think about it is that you are trying to take a bunch of dot products between the vectors in `X` and the vectors in `AX`. Matlab has a function for that:

```
N = 10; % number of x's
M = 100; % length of x's
X = rand(M,N);
A = rand(M, M);

% way 1
way1 = diag(X' * A * X);

% way 2
way2 = dot(X, A*X)';

% compare
[way1 way2]
```

Comment: Ah okay. I was kind of hoping for a more elegant solution that would let me keep it as a matrix multiplication, but it seems like there might not be one. Thanks anyhow!

Comment: Isn't this really inefficient? It computes at least n**2 more operations than needed. Isn't there any better solution?

Comment: @FarhoodET are you talking about way 1 or way 2?

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
sum((A*X).*X,1)
```

Or, if you are dealing with complex values,

```
sum((A*X).*conj(X),1)
```

Check:

```
>> A = rand(4,4);
>> X = rand(4,3);
>> sum((A*X).*X,1)
ans =
    5.4755    2.6205    3.4803
>> diag(X'*A*X)
ans =
    5.4755
    2.6205
    3.4803
```

Comment: Equivalent to `dot( X, A*X )` in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

This could be one approach, though not sure if this would be more efficient than the `direct matrix multiplication + diag` based approach -

```
%// Perform X'*A equivalent multiplication
mult1 = bsxfun(@times,permute(X,[1 3 2]),A)

%// Perform rest of the equivalent multiplication
mult2 = bsxfun(@times,mult1,permute(X,[3 1 2]))

%// Perform the summations required to reduce to desired output's size
out = sum(reshape(mult2,[],size(X,2)),1)
```

---

You can  re-arrange the multiplications a bit -

```
mult1  = bsxfun(@times,permute(X,[1 3 2]),permute(X,[3 1 2]))
mult2 = bsxfun(@times,mult1,A)
out = sum(reshape(mult2,[],size(X,2)),1)
```

---

Or merge the ending `bsxfun(@times` and `sum` with a bit more simplified and maybe more efficient version -

```
mult1  = bsxfun(@times,permute(X,[1 3 2]),permute(X,[3 1 2]))
out = reshape(permute(mult1,[3 1 2]),size(X,2),[])*A(:)
```

---

Or simplify it further to make it a one-liner that uses minimal of tools and could be the most efficient of the lot! -

```
out = reshape(bsxfun(@times,X.',permute(X,[2 3 1])),[],numel(A))*A(:)
```

Answer (score 0):

In numpy, you can do np.einsum('ij,jk,ki->i',np.transpose(X),A,X).